# How to convert dateTime to Microsoft Timestamp in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I am facing problem when trying to convert DateTime format in flutter to integer similar to format in Microsoft Excel, due to the backend-service parameter need integer similar to '44xxx' according to the DateTime(). Is there any ways to convert this ?

Comment: If you simply want to convert `datetime` object to time that is is to interpret, you can do it with `intl` library in flutter.

You can read more about it here,
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/intl-library.html

You can get the `intl` package from `pub`,
https://pub.dev/packages/intl

Comment: Sorry, I would like to convert to microsoft timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```dart
final startOfTime = DateTime(1899, 12, 30);
double microsoftTimeStamp(DateTime date) {
  final diff = date.difference(startOfTime);
  return diff.inDays + ((diff - Duration(days: diff.inDays)).inSeconds / 86400);
}
```

Edit: the microsoft timestamp actually considers 1900-02-29 as a real date so using 1899-12-30 gives the correct result as long as you don’t need dates before 1900-03-01

Comment: Thanks bro. The method is working. By the way, can you provide me the method for convert the microsoftTimeStamp to DateTime in Flutter?

Comment: Thats simply `startOfTime.add(Duration(days: timestamp.toInt(), seconds: (timestamp % 1 * 86400).toInt());`